# Changing Yellowbrick visiualization colors

Tags: python-3.x, yellowbrick

In Yellowbrick visiualization library, the default color for the classification report is red: from lighter to darker tones. Is there a way to change this color and use green, blue, etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when defining the visualizer, you can set a color sequence(cmap).

```
viz = ClassificationReport(model,  cmap='PuRd')
viz.score(X_test, y_test)
```

[image: PurpletoRedReport]

You can find the different color sequences at

http://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/palettes.html#color-sequences